# Google Colab & Teradata Driver Not Found

Tags: python, odbc, driver, teradata, google-colaboratory

### Context:

I am currently trying to use Google Colab at work -- for sharing purposes -- as our company uses GMail as default email network.

When I run Jupyter Notebooks locally, everything goes well and I can connect to Teradata (latest driver installed locally is `16.10.12.00`, driver can be found at `teradata.tdodbc.drivers` as `'Teradata Database ODBC Driver 16.20'` and I am using Teradata module to connect.

### Problem:

When I try the same configuration at a Google Colab Notebook, I can't connect, getting a `InterfaceError: ('DRIVER_NOT_FOUND', "No driver found for 'Teradata'.  Available drivers: ")` error.

When checking the driver information, it seems the driver installed is  version `15.10.0.21` and the driver can't be found using `teradata.tdodbc.drivers` -- the print is empty.

### Possible questions:

> 1. How to install the latest Teradata Driver on Google Colab, as I am using on my local setup?;
> 2. How to fill `teradata.tdodbc.drivers` with driver data as my local setup has?;
> 3. How to guarantee the Teradata Module is loading the driver information of the installed driver (`15.10.0.21`)?

### Reproduce the problem:

1. Open a [Google Colab Notebook](https://colab.research.google.com)
2. Install Teradata Module using `!pip install teradata`
3. Install the list of possible dependencies to make Teradata module work

`%%bash
apt-get install build-essential zlib1g-dev libsdl2-dev libjpeg-dev \
nasm tar libbz2-dev libgtk2.0-dev cmake git libfluidsynth-dev libgme-dev \
libopenal-dev timidity libwildmidi-dev unzip
apt-get install libboost-all-dev
apt-get install liblua5.1-dev`

4. Check the driver using `teradata.tdodbc.drivers`: the list will be empty.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: It looks like the drivers are distributed separately: https://downloads.teradata.com/download/connectivity/odbc-driver/linux